# Make same order of similar column in two data frames

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have two data frames - `DF1` and `DF2`

```
DF1
    RS1    R_Al1     B
    rs_12   A       -0.1
    rs_23   T        0.2
    rs_34   C        0.3

DF2
RS2   RefAl2   B
rs_12   C       0.5
rs_23   G      -0.3
rs_23   T       0.2
rs_34   C      -0.1
rs_23   G      -0.1
rs_34   C       0.7
rs_34   A       0.9
```

I need to get same order of Columns `RS1` and `RS2`. How can i do it if length of column differ between two data frames.

**UPDATE**

Expected output would be `DF2$RS2` which would have order as in `DF1$RS1` :

```
DF2$RS2

RS2    
rs_12
rs_23
rs_23
rs_23
rs_34
rs_34
rs_34
```

Comment: What do you mean by the same order? Do you just want them to go from rs_1 to rs_3?

Comment: Yes but i cant apply sort

Comment: Can you add expected output? Are you trying to merge and get Bs for alelle1 and allele2?

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you, i updated the question now.

Comment: No, it can not be removed. I thought what if to convert DF1$RS1 to factor, get its order and then apply it to DF2$RS2. But i got error that the length of DF1 and DF2 differs

Comment: @HoHoHo could you give us the bigger picture, why are we doing this?

Comment: @coffeinjunky I am guessing, these are dbSNP ids, e.g.: [rs6983267](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?searchType=adhoc_search&type=rs&rs=rs6983267), removing `rs` and sorting as number wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try with `match` and `order`

```
DF2[order(match(DF2$RS2, DF1$RS1)),1, drop=FALSE]
#   RS2
#1 rs_12
#2 rs_23
#3 rs_23
#5 rs_23
#4 rs_34
#6 rs_34
#7 rs_34
```